# How to remove installed Viber sticker?

Tags: viber-messenger

I don't know how to remove the installed sticker in Viber list. Mine is quite long now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not yet supported.

From [viberfaq](http://www.viberfaq.com/viber-stickers-emoticons-and-locations/#comment-1167546961) (answer posted a month ago):

> At the moment it is unfortunately not possible. You can uninstall
>   Viber, and when you reinstall, Stickers will be gone from your Sticker
>   folder (but this will unfortunately result in message history
>   deletion).
>
> In the future we plan to add a feature that lets you remove Stickers
>   from your folder.